# Plotting a million points in R?

Tags: r, statistics

i have a text file (tab delimited) and it has 3 columns A, B, C:

```
       A                          B                           C
0.07142857142857142      0.35714285714285715    0.21428571428571427
0.0                      0.3333333333333333     0.3888888888888889
0.07142857142857142      0.35714285714285715    0.21428571428571427
0.0                      0.3333333333333333         0.3888888888888889
```

Each row represents a sample with 3 different percentages A, B and C. In total I have 4 files for 4 different organisms.
There can be more than a million rows per file.

My idea is to plot each row in order to see the distribution of the pairs of points (A,B,C) in a given file and then to determine what is the most frequent pair in a given file and then compare the 4 files.

I tried plotting these points in R (multi-curves in a same graph: A, B, C in the y axis and the number of sample in the x axis) for each file but there are so many points that basically the graph can't be interpreted. Also for the million rows file, R crashes and won't plot the points.

What would be the best approach to represent these points? Also is the mode function enough to determine the most frequent pair (A,B,C) or is there any appropriate statistic test I could try to do so?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of data are you dealing with? You mention "organisms", so maybe have a look around in the Bioconductor project: http://www.bioconductor.org/help/workflows/highthroughputassays/#diverse-assays-resources . Maybe you're dealing with some common task which may have some dedicated package to analyse the data.

Comment: Sounds like you want a clustering algorithm: http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Cluster.html

Comment: Hi and thanks a lot for you answer.
So each row represents a protein and the percentages A, B, C represent a percentage of a certain structure for the given protein. This is something that hasn't really done before so I couldn't find something appropriate to this specific issue but I think some statistical approaches can be used as the clustering answer can be a good thing to try. I'll have a look at that. Thanks.

Comment: I just looked at the bioconductor project and it seems interesting as well, I'll have a better look. Thanks.

Comment: Hi again, The cluster algorithm seems very interesting but it seems like it clusters points with a given coordinate (x,y). How would you go to cluster for a given position x, a pair of points (A,B,C) that have the same x coordinate?

Comment: Is your goal to produce a clusterplot for presentation, or to come up with an estimate of "most frequent" pairs in each file?  If the latter, skip the plotting and do some subsetting & histogram-binning.

Comment: Actually, both are my goals, I'd like to see what is the most frequent pair and represent it graphically. I have tried to do some histogram but as I said previously, the number of rows can be up to 1 million and hence, the graph is not nice and interpretable because all points overlap with each other and we can't see much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, [clustering](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Cluster.html) may be a solution to your problem. Here is one way of clustering using `kmeans`:

```
irisCl <- transform(iris, Cluster = kmeans(iris[1:4],3)$cluster)
library(ggplot2)
qplot(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, data=irisCl, colour=Species) + facet_grid(~Cluster)
```

[image: kmeans]

Note that we have clustered in a 4-dimensional variable space. As you can see, the setosa are identified correctly in the first cluster, the second cluster contains only virginica, but the third cluster contains a mixture of versicolor and virginica.

Comment: Thank you very much for this clear explanation. Do you mean that the third cluster contains pair of versicolor and viriginica that occurs at the same time?

Comment: It means that the data is too close (using the Euclidean distance measure) to separate them out.

Comment: Oh ok, so basically, it will show me all the x that have the same exact pair of (A,B,C) but also all the x that have close (A.B.C) values?
Does this function accept a file as parameter? Thanks again.

Comment: You have to provide it with data and the number of clusters you want. See `?kmeans` for more information.

Comment: Hi again,

I've given it a try:

    fd <- read.table("C:/Users/emi/Desktop/Res.txt", header= TRUE, sep = "\t", col.names=c("A", "B", "C"))
    data <- table(sprintf("%s:%s:%s", fd$A, fd$B, fd$C))
    fit <- kmeans(data, 5)
    library(ggplot2)
    plot(fit)

But i get an error : Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y'

What am I doing wrong?